# URL encode string in ios failing

Tags: ios5, automatic-ref-counting, urlencode, cfstring

I am trying to url encode a string in my iOS 5 app using ARC.

This is how i do it:

```
- (NSString *)escape:(NSString *)text
{
    return (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                          (__bridge CFStringRef)text, NULL,
                                          (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                          kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}
```

I then call it with test data like this:

```
NSLog([self escape:@"kalel///&&&???"]);
```

But the output i get from the `NSLog` is this:

```
kalel0.0000000.0000000.00000022623F0.0000000.000000
```

That just does not seem right, but no matter what I can't get it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `escape` function is fine. The problem is in a way you call `NSLog`:

`escape` produces the string `kalel%2F%2F%2F%26%26%26%3F%3F%3F` for your input. `NSLog` interprets this string as a format string and prints some garbage as floating point numbers right after `kalel` word!

You should always call `NSLog` with a string constant as a first argument, e.g.:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self escape:@"kalel///&&&???"]);
```

**P.S.** You have a memory leak in `escape` --- you should `return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)` as you transfer retained CF object to Objective C space.